# Is code running in client or as batch job?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

Is there any way to determine whether the code is being executed in the client or in a batch job ? I thought of using [`curUserId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa630899.aspx) and checking if the user is the one we use for batch jobs, but this approach fails if the user is ever changed.

I'm trying to modify the `update` method of table `VendTable` with a Yes/No dialog when it's run into a client, but I don't want this happening when the code runs as batch.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your batch class that extends `runbasebatch`, you can use `this.isInBatch()`. This will return true if code runs in batch and false if not running in batch. You can then pass this as a parameter to other classes. (I would recommend doing it this way).

One note though, you shouldn't be showing a dialog in the `update` method of the `VendTable` table because you should never have user interaction in a transaction which I assume will be the case.

If you want to have user interaction when a user writes a record on a form, try overwriting the write method of you form datasource. This will be executed when a record is written (inserted, updated). You can ask for user input here. For an example, check the purchtable form (purchtable ds, write method), it should contain something similar (it asks to copy fields from header to line)

Comment: Sorry, I corrected where I want to do this. Does putting that dialog before any `ttsbegin` count as having "user interaction in a transaction" ?

Comment: Hi Francis. If the code is in the `update` method, it will always be in a transaction because otherwise the update fails. If you put your dialog before all `ttsbegin` call, it will not be in a transaction. However it could be that your code is called by other code that does create a transaction. You could check on `appl.ttsLevel() == 0`, which checks if the current ttlevel is `0`. Btw the problem with user interaction in a transaction, is that it can cause long running transactions and unbalanced ttslevels. Try to adjust your design :-).

Comment: I removed the part about xsession, it's not bullet proof so you better not use it. The best thing is to have your user interaction first, then do your business logic. If you can't do this, use `isinbatch()` but this will only work on you batch class.

Comment: So if I want the dialog to pop up when users modify vendors in the client, I'd be better modifying the code of the "Save" button not the `update` method. I don't know if that's possible, I'll look into it.

Comment: Francis, this overwriting the `write` method of you form datasource. This will be executed when a record is written (inserted, updated). You can ask for user input here. For an example, check the purchtable form (purchtable ds, write method), it should contain something similar (it asks to copy fields from header to line)

Comment: Thanks Klaas. If you add your last comment in your answer, I'll flag it as answer.